# Regex to add a comma after every sequence of digits in a string

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex or something to loop on all numbers in a string and add a comma after them. but if there is already a comma then it shouldn't do it.

Example:

```
$string="21 Beverly hills 90010, CA";
```

Output:

```
$string="21, beverly hills 90010, CA";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=\d\b)(?!,)/', ',', $string);
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d\b) # Assert that the current position is to the right of a digit
          # and that this digit is the last one in a number 
          # (\b = word boundary anchor).
(?!,)     # Assert that there is no comma to the right of the current position
```

Then just insert a comma in this position. Done.

This will not insert a comma between a number and a letter (it will not change `21A Broadway` into `21,A Broadway`) because `\b` only matches between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters. If you do want this, use `/(?<=\d)(?![\d,])/` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to be careful about what your input was, since this could have unexpected results with some strings.

```
preg_replace('/([0-9])(\s)/', '$1,$2', $string);
```

EDIT in response to the comment below -- here's a version if your numbers are not necessarily followed by spaces. Results could be even more unexpected.

```
preg_replace('/([0-9])([^,0-9])/', '$1,$2', '21 Beverly hills 90010, CA');
```

Comment: David never said that numbers would be followed by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Possessive quantifier (`++`) and negative lookahead should do the trick:

```
$string="21 Beverly hills 90010, CA";

echo preg_replace('/\d++(?!,)/', '$0,', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work if the numbers are always followed by spaces.

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\d+)(\s)/', '$1,$2', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break this into two steps. First, remove all existing commas after numbers. Second, add commas after all numbers.

```
$string = preg_replace('/([0-9]+),/', '$1', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/([0-9]+)/', '$1,', $string);
```